# composer update without a cascade update

Tags: php, git, bash, composer-php

I own two projects

-The project A

-The project B

---

Project A "require" project B (with @dev version)

Project B "require **lot of stuff**"

When I do a

> composer update myname/project_b

composer also makes an update of "**lot of stuff**", which can be time consuming, and I have to update frequently without knowing if the package has changed.

So I had the idea to make a script with the following algorithm: 
`Partial update (~=git pull) of *myname/project_b*; 
If *vendor/myname/project_b* has changed {
    do a full composer update.
}`

The problem is that I have no idea how to do the "partial update".
A git pull on the vendor directory keep prompt for username and password.

Another approach could be to retrieve the id of the last commit of the repository with the version taken by composer, but again, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You shouldnt be using dev unless your developing the packages :/, Once your happy your app works you should lock the versions in your composer file. There is no reason to have master version of packages on a production site that's for dev/staging.. time shouldn't be the main reason for not wanting to composer update :/

Comment: your composer update command would only update your project_b and leave the installed versions of "lot of stuff" like they are. are you sure that you are not deleting the composer.lock / vendor folder in your project in between?

Comment: @lawrence-cheroneI : I develop packets, which is why I need to update them frequently. If it was for production, I would not bother creating a script and I would make a complete update

Comment: @Norman M : I asked myself the question about the duration of the composer update "myname / project_b", so I launched the command with -vvv (ultra verbose), "lot of stuff" is realy updated